# Implementation oAuth2 in angular 8

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am new to angular trying to implement authentication using oAuth2.I have implemented the server-side with spring boot tested with postman it's working fine. I am not able to send `cient_id` and `password` in request header can anyone help with an example implementation oAuth2 in angular 8.

```
    @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {

  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) { }

  UserAuthentication(UserName: string, Password: string): Observable<any> { 
   let oauth2_client_id = 'Sharath';
   let oauth2_client_secret = 'Testing@1234';

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization':'Basic'+ btoa("sharath" + ':' + "Testing@1234"),
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })
    };

    const body = 'password=secret&username=user&grant_type=password&client_id=sharath&client_secret=Testing@1234';

   return this.httpclient.post<any>('http://localhost:9090/oauth/token', body , httpOptions);    
 }   
}
```

Comment: You should provide some code how you try to do that

Comment: Angular/SPA can't expose client secret - you need to use different flow e.g. `OpenID Connect Code Flow with PKCE` and use some ready certified library to do that https://openid.net/developers/certified/